# When making a new Scanner is there a downside to using the same input name?

Tags: java, input

I've just learned about scanners but one thing I noticed was when I wrote

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner object
System.out.println("Enter a line: "); //Ask for input
String line = input.nextLine(); //Enter input
System.out.println("You entered: " + line); //Output the input
System.out.println("And enter a number: ");
int value = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(value + " " + line);
```

the top line of code could be used for both thing I wanted to get input for (string and ints). My question is whether I should be using the same name for a scanner 'input' in this case for multiple things i'd like to input. I'm new so even if I can't find a problem that could come from using the same name, if later on in a big program this could become problematic?

Comment: It's not "using the same name" it's "using the same object".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Why will he need another scanner instance pointing to the same InputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the scanner instance `input` is a *reference* and you are making it point to the *standard* input stream by *specifying* `new Scanner(System.in);`.

In a *stream*, everything will be in *bytes*, the methods `nextLine()` , `nextInt()` etc will *scan / parse* the stream and give you the data of that *particular type.

So using the *same scanner instance* i.e, `input` is fine because you are *parsing data* as you receive it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same scanner object until its not closed and pointing to input stream.
If you don't need it anymore then use close method to close the Scanner.